# Qt QOpenGLWidget glClearColor not functioning correctly

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a slight problem when calling glClearColor from various places outside of paintGL(). The aim is to enable the user to set the clear colour on the fly but this is not working as planned unless glClearColor is called each frame in paintGL.

Aim:

```
void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_lastPos = event->pos();
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //<-- Doesn't change clear colour
}
```

Non-optimal workaround:

```
void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_lastPos = event->pos();
    r = 1.0f;
    g = 0.0f;
    b = 0.0f;
    a = 1.0f;
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
...
```

I assume this has something to do with how Qt swaps buffers and updates the screen but it's not clear what exactly is causing it. Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume this has something to do with how Qt swaps buffers and updates the screen but it's not clear what exactly is causing it. Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Wrong, it has to do with doing OpenGL calls with no OpenGL context bound. **You must call `makeCurrent` before doing any OpenGL call**.

Why does it work in `paintGL` then? Because Qt makes the context current automatically before calling `paintGL`, `resizeGL` and `initializeGL` (see their documentation).

Comment: I cannot believe that was the issue. I assumed the context would remain current unless another was bound. Thanks for the quick reply, I'll mark as answered as soon as enough time has passed.

Comment: @AnthonyQuinn I don't know how Qt handles OpenGL rendering, but it's common in other frameworks to use a separate thread for rendering. If that's the case, you won't have a current OpenGL context in the UI thread, where you handle mouse input.

Comment: In this scenario there's no threading going on in Qt at all. In general, you should not assume that the context has been kept bound -- what if another library / subsystem / etc. makes another context current? In the specific case, Qt itself makes (at least) *another* context bound in that thread, so in `mousePressEvent` you have no idea of which one is the current context, if any. That's why `makeCurrent` exists after all.

Comment: How could I call OpenGL functions from outside the main GLWidget class (my own class which inherits from QOpenGLWidget and QOpenGLFunctions). I can retrieve the current context (well the last one to be made current) by using QOpenGL::currentContext() but makeCurrent  now requires a surface reference. Do I need a static method to expose this or is there a more suitable way?

Comment: If you call `currentContext` the context is already current, by definition, so you don't need to call `makeCurrent` on it. Just be sure to have *one* context current, for instance by calling `yourGlWidget->makeCurrent()` before calling such OpenGL functions (outside).

Comment: I'll explain my situation clearer as I'm still struggling on the correct way to call gl functions from outside of my `GLWidget` class. I have another class which inherits from `QLineEdit` in which the `textChanged` signal is detected and handled, parsing the hex colour into rgba. As this method does not have reference to a `GLWidget` instance and `GLWidget` does not know when text has been changed, where should `makeCurrent()` be called?
Sorry for the amount of questions, I'm still trying to get my head around Qt's implementation of OpenGL.

Comment: I guess I was looking for a optimal solution rather than just a workaround and forgot the spirit of stackoverflow. My solution is now to make a static pointer to the GLWidget instance with a static method to `makeCurrent` and `doneCurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think @peppe answer correctly because
[You don't need to call makeCurrent() since Qt have already to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9KFE.png)

In my opinion, what you really need is just an `update()` call in `mousePressEvent`.

[If you wan't to call paintGL() to update, what you need is just to call update()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wl5z.png)

Also, you should know that in `glClearColor()`, you only set the clearColor attribute on OpenGL state machine. `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` is the true function which actually clear the color buffer. So you should set clearColor by `glClearColor()` before calling `glClear()`.

if I were you, the code would be like:

```cpp
void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_lastPos = event->pos();
    r = 1.0f;
    g = 0.0f;
    b = 0.0f;
    a = 1.0f;
    update();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```